# InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified - although locking the collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

I have a synchronized hashtable, from which I regularly remove some entries. Multiple threads run this code. So I lock the entire foreach, but I still sometimes get InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified ... at Hashtable.HashtableEnumerator.MoveNext() - i.e. in the foreach loop.
What am I doing wrong? Isn't locking enough?

```
private static readonly Hashtable sessionsTimeoutData = Hashtable.Synchronized(new Hashtable(5000));
```

private static void ClearTimedoutSessions()
{
    List keysToRemove = new List();
    long now = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    lock (sessionsTimeoutData)
    {
        TimeoutData timeoutData;
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in sessionsTimeoutData)
        {
            timeoutData = (TimeoutData)entry.Value;
            if (now - timeoutData.LastAccessTime > timeoutData.UserTimeoutTicks)
                keysToRemove.Add((ulong)entry.Key);
        }
    }
    foreach (ulong key in keysToRemove)
        sessionsTimeoutData.Remove(key);
}

Comment: Pro tip: unless you're stuck in .NET 1.1, use the generic versions. They're faster, safer and better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to lock using `SyncRoot` which is the object that the methods for a synchronized `Hashtable` will lock on:

```
lock (sessionsTimeoutData.SyncRoot)
{
    // ...
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.synchronized.aspx:

> Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. Even when a collection is
>   synchronized, other threads can still
>   modify the collection, which causes
>   the enumerator to throw an exception.
>   To guarantee thread safety during
>   enumeration, you can either lock the
>   collection during the entire
>   enumeration or catch the exceptions
>   resulting from changes made by other
>   threads.
>
> The following code example shows how
>   to lock the collection using the
>   SyncRoot during the entire
>   enumeration:
>
> ```
> Hashtable myCollection = new Hashtable();
> lock(myCollection.SyncRoot)
> {
>     foreach (object item in myCollection)
>     {
>         // Insert your code here.
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: That's a good idea, but the real problem is that the second foreach (the one that's removing data) is outside the lock.

Comment: @Etienne: each `Remove()` call will be synchronized (will take the lock internally). The collection will remain consistent - updates to the collection might take place between removes, but each `Remove()` call will be fine. Depending on the behavior of the application, it's possible that you could have a race where the object with that key gets replaced by a another thread and depending on the needs of the application it might not be correct to remove the updated key/value pair. But that's a different problem than what the OP is running into.

Answer (score 2):

Why is the second foreach outside of the lock?

Comment: I don't get why it should be inside the lock. My only concern is when I'm enumerating the hashtable, no other thread could modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock while you remove as well as while you are calculating what to remove.  Move this,

```
foreach (ulong key in keysToRemove)
        sessionsTimeoutData.Remove(key);
```

Into your locked section.