# WPF framework using Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher in background thread, causing memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I'm using a WPF CollectionView and I'm setting the Filter in a background thread, because it takes a long time to apply this filter.

Setting this Filter triggers the method [ScheduleMapCleanup](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/CollectionViewGroupInternal.cs.html#https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/CollectionViewGroupInternal.cs.html,88fffd8bbbb41f50,references)() of CollectionView (so WPF framework code I can't change). In this method, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke is used.

However, because this is executed in a background thread, this Action is never executed (the Dispatcher of this thread is never started), causing a memory leak: The Dispatcher keeps a reference to the CollectionView.

How could I work around this problem? Setting the Filter in the UI thread is not an option.

Could I start the Dispatcher myself? If so, how do I do this (Dispatcher.Run halts everything)?

Comment: Can you add some of your code? How you are doing it?

Comment: There isn't really much code to show. I'm just doing collectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(MyFunction); in a background thread.

This triggers the ScheduleMapCleanup() method, which you find here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/CollectionViewGroupInternal.cs.html#https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/CollectionViewGroupInternal.cs.html,88fffd8bbbb41f50,references

There Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher is used. Which isn't running.

Comment: Despite your 'Setting the Filter in the UI thread is not an option.', did you try it and what did happen? Applying the filter should not really block the UI.

Comment: "Setting the Filter in the UI thread is not an option." Why?  The `CollectionViewSource` is explicitly documented as not being thread safe.

Comment: @Mitch: Setting the Filter property can take up to several minutes (depending on the number of items in the list and the complexity of the filter). So it's not really an option to freeze the UI during that time. By setting it in a background thread, the UI stays usable and I can show a nice loading indication to the user.

Comment: @Lander, then you need to fix that performance issue or filter your collection before passing it to `CollectionViewSource`.

Comment: @Mitch, in an ideal world yes. But in this case that wasn't possible (for non-technical reasons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear: I don't use Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher in my code. This is used in the WPF framework code, so I can't change this. 
This code is executed in a background thread because I'm setting the Filter in a background thread. I'm setting this property in a background thread because it can take up to several minutes. Setting it in a background thread keeps the UI responsive and lets me show a loading indication to the user.

I fixed the memory leak (caused by the not-running background Dispatcher keeping a reference to the CollectionView) by adding a Shutdown to the Dispatcher and starting the dispatcher in the background thread:

```
//All code below is executed on a background thread

//Line below causes WPF framework to add something to Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher queue.
view.Filter = new Predicate<Object>(actionTarget.FilterCallback); 

if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground &&  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher != Application.Current.Dispatcher)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
    Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

If the background thread is reused later (for example because it's a thread pool thread, started by a BackgroundWorker) you can't use BeginInvokeShutdown like in the code above: a shut down dispatcher can not be started again. In that case, use this instead of the BeginInvokeShutdown:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate() { Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames(); }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

This will make sure the Run() method returns, but the dispatcher can be started again later on.

Edit: As Mitch mentioned in comment below, be carefull when multiple threads can be executing the Run() at the same time. If necessary add a lock around the Run().

Comment: That was a really interesting case to understand the dispatcher use thanks!

Comment: This will cause random exceptions, since you have effectively removed the synchronization provided by only using one dispatcher.

Comment: @Mitch, there is only one action executed on that second dispatcher and it doesn't need synchronization with the UI thread.

Comment: @Lander, how do you figure? It is both enumerating and modifying the contents of a `HashTable`, which is not thread safe.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5762512/138200

Comment: @Mitch, you're right. But in my case only one thread at a time can set the Filter of a specific CollectionView, so this doesn't cause a problem. I'll add the warning to my answer though.

Comment: @Lander, no.  A read to `_nameToGroupMap` is enough to cause an exception.  One thread writing (your background thread), one thread reading (the WPF thread) will throw.  A test app which repeatedly sets the filter reliably produces an exception for me within a second of opening.  This will, of course be dependent upon race conditions.

Comment: @Mitch: This error has probably never occurred in my application (after several years) because the CollectionView is detached from it's view before the Filter is set in a background thread.

Comment: Even assuming your situation works without exceptions (which is questionable), your answer is advocating the use of undefined behavior with exception throwing race conditions.  You do not prescribe use of `Dispatcher.Run()` in an exceedingly specific case, but as a general solution to using `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` in a background thread.  The correct solution is _"Don't do it."_

Answer (score 1):

I use this when I need to update some controls and binding on my UI thread from my background tasks:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
    new Action(() => {

        // Code here

    })
);
```

If it's not this can you be more specific on what you want to do on your UI thread

Comment: I can't change the code calling Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher. It's part of the WPF framework.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't understand the question my bad

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the current dispatcher from a background thread does not give you the UI dispatcher, it gives you a new one for the background thread.

Either call `CurrentDispatcher` from the foreground thread and pass the result to the background thread, or call `DependencyObject.Dispatcher` to get the dispatcher for a window or other control.

---

Edit: I just read the question more closely.  Since you do not control the code calling `CurrentDispatcher`, the only way that it will work is to call that code from the UI thread.